# wordpress multisite without root blog

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to setup a wordpress multisite with no blog on `/`

I've got two sites

```
/sv
/en
```

and everything is installed in the root so I can access `/wp-admin`

The problem seems to be that the multisite setup requires one site in the table `wp_blogs` to be located at `path = /` to work.

I start by setting up an ordinary wordpress 4.1 setup on `/sv` which the nginx redirects to if `/` is visited.

I then want to add the english site and enable mutltisite in `wp-config.php`

and go through the network setup and add

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'mysite.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/sv');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

But when I then try to access `/wp-admin` it says the database is not found, even though I know it works.

So my question is, can I setup multisite without a `wp_blogs` mapped to `/`?

Comment: Why don't you add an url redirect template on / ? So if somebody open your base url domain.tld/, it redirects to /en or /sv, so it looks like there is no main site.

Comment: The problem is that wordpress multisite doesn't seem to be able to work without a blog bound to  /. I've already fixed the redirect from / to /sv with nginx

Comment: @LeonRadley it's not the problem actually, it's how the system supposed to work.WP Multisite concept is a "Network with main site".

Comment: @Ihor-paspar2.com But if I want the main site to be /sv and the secondary to be /en that isn't possible? I would still have to have a third site with nothing on it that would live under / ?

Comment: Yes, empty site with ID 1, and redirect it to /sv on the early stage. I'm adding the code as an answer right now.

Answer (score 0):

It's the way WP Network supposed to work - a network of sites with one main site. To get what you want, you need to have a main site (usually with ID 1) and on the very early stage redirect your users to a subsite:

`function my_redirect() {
    wp_redirect( network_site_url( '/sv' ), 301 );
    exit();
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_redirect' );`